# Unable to insert multipolygon WFS-T GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, wfs-t, insert

I got following insert XML WFS transactions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Transaction xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
  <Insert>
    <equipaments_copy xmlns="xxx">
      <geom>
        <MultiPolygon srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#25831">
          <polygonMember>
            <Polygon>
              <exterior>
                <LinearRing>
                  <posList>419834.94350044 4581816.95425736 419849.64534847 4581820.41660114 419854.55439083 4581809.0465984 419854.78626612 4581808.50954382 419852.970256 4581807.54655611 419842.41420174 4581802.54862851 419841.54615645 4581802.1597275 419837.95017966 4581800.5486593 419831.47560517 4581815.64886866 419831.28528725 4581816.09273379 419834.94350044 4581816.95425736</posList>
                </LinearRing>
              </exterior>
            </Polygon>
          </polygonMember>
        </MultiPolygon>
      </geom>
      <nom>3337</nom>
    </equipaments_copy>
  </Insert>
</Transaction>
```

Also tried this one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Transaction xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
  <Insert>
    <equipaments_copy xmlns="xxx">
      <geom>
        <MultiPolygon srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#25831">
          <polygonMember>
            <Polygon>
              <outerBoundaryIs>
                <LinearRing>
                  <coordinates xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml" decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">419834.94350044,4581816.95425736 419849.64534847,4581820.41660114 419854.55439083,4581809.0465984 419854.78626612,4581808.50954382 419852.970256,4581807.54655611 419842.41420174,4581802.54862851 419841.54615645,4581802.1597275 419837.95017966,4581800.5486593 419831.47560517,4581815.64886866 419831.28528725,4581816.09273379 419834.94350044,4581816.95425736</coordinates>
                </LinearRing>
              </outerBoundaryIs>
            </Polygon>
          </polygonMember>
        </MultiPolygon>
      </geom>
      <nom>3337</nom>
    </equipaments_copy>
  </Insert>
</Transaction>
```

When sending to GeoServer it creates object with no geom object with no error.
[image]

Property of geometry is set to MultiPolygon with name geom.
[image: geom]

Any idea of what is wrong with this Insert? Why geom object is not getting set?

Comment: One is GML 2 and the other is GML 3,  unless you change the version of WFS you are using it won't work.

Comment: the problem that no one is working

Comment: Are you using PostGIS datastore or what?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: also, do you really use `xxx` as the namespace URI or are you trying to redact something? That uri has to match the workspace URI of the features you are adding

Comment: xxx is in reality client's private workspace that's why i wrote xxx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was i was hitting WFS 1.1.0 instead of 1.0.0 which works with MultiPolygon.
WFS 1.1.0 works with MultiSurface
Changing
this
version="1.1.0"
to
version="1.0.0"
now sets geom object.